# perfect forwarding / move construction isn't working from tuple in std::apply

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to construct the perfect forwarded (zero copied) construction using nested lambda captures.
I expect that there should be zero copy constructions, but something is broken.

I move from variadic arg. pack to tuple (moved ok) then I pass the tuple (moved ok) to the std::apply and in final nested lambda I assemble another tuple (expected to be moved ok but Wrapper CTOR is COPY not MOVE:

```
#include <iostream>

// tuple printer (ignore it)
template<typename Type, unsigned N, unsigned Last>
struct tuple_printer {
    static void print(std::ostream& out, const Type& value) {
        out << std::get<N>(value) << ", ";
        tuple_printer<Type, N + 1, Last>::print(out, value);
    }
};

template<typename Type, unsigned N>
struct tuple_printer<Type, N, N> {
    static void print(std::ostream& out, const Type& value) {
        out << std::get<N>(value);
    }
};

template<typename... Types>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::tuple<Types...>& value) {
    out << "(";
    tuple_printer<std::tuple<Types...>, 0, sizeof...(Types) - 1>::print(out, value);
    out << ")";
    return out;
}

// THE FUNCTION that returns lambda:
template <class ... Args>
auto f(Args && ... args)
{
    // v--- args is a tuple<arg1, arg2, arg3 ...>
    return [args_upper = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()
    {
        // v-- lower "args" is a restored list of arguments - moved from the upper tuple "args"
        return std::apply([](auto && ... args) {
            // v--- here the Wrapper COPY-CTOR is called instead of moved from
            return std::make_tuple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        }, std::move(args_upper));
    };
}

struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper() {
        std::cout << "CTOR ";
    }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper & r) {
        std::cout << "COPY-CTOR ";
    }
    Wrapper(Wrapper&& r) {
        std::cout << "MOVE-CTOR ";
    }
    int w = 42;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Wrapper& w);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Wrapper& w) {
    out << w.w;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    auto l = f(1,2.f,"st", Wrapper{});
    auto t = l(); // t is tuple
    std::cout << t; // tuple printer
//    std::cout << l();
}
```

Gives an output CTOR MOVE-CTOR COPY-CTOR (1, 2, st, 42)

Comment: I think the crux here is the `decltype(args)`, which could result in a refernce type being passed. But `std::forward` expects the class name without any reference in general. Have you tried `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: @ThomasLang decltype(auto) is only for a function return type deduction. I tried std::forward<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(args)>>(args)...); but still a copy construction occurs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return [args_upper = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()
```

change this to

```
return [args_upper = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]() mutable
```

`args_upper` is implicitly `const` unless you make your lambda `mutable`.  That'll block move semantics.

Comment: it worked! how did you know? i.e what is the general strategy here to think about the constness? i.e how did you know??))

Comment: @barney Just remember that when you capture by value you cannot change the value as lambdas are implicitly `const`, unless you mark them as `mutable`.

Comment: @barney Think about lambdas in terms of an unnamed struct with a (by default) const `operator()` being your given function body and any captures being members. You can remove the `const` from the `operator()` by adding the `mutable` keyword.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes, that's why its always useful to know the underlying "physical" model - to build the proper mental image of "what is it" and "how is it constructed under the hood" - to see those tiny details like the `const`-ness of the `operator()`

Comment: @barney I thought "ok, you are trying to move and it is copying. That probably means you are screwing up perfect forwarding -- lrvalueness of some references.  Hmm, nope, it appears you have l/r value right.  Well, next possibility is you are trying to move-from-`const`.  Ayep, right there."  Like most things, it is a matter of having made that mistake before.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont thanks, Adam, I bet the real experience really matters) but you made your thinking strategy explicit - and its really valuable for other developers ) appreciate it